# Error while calculating dot product in Theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano, deep-learning

I have the following simple code written in Theano and I am getting error while compiling function f:

```
import theano.tensor as T
x = T.dmatrix('x')
w = T.dmatrix('w')
y = T.dot(x,w)

f = function([x,w],y)

ImportError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', Dot22(x, w), '\n', 'dlopen(../.theano/compiledir_Darwin-13.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.8-64/tmpTqQ0iS/b6135ddd19d268ad3182850548638ec3.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib\n  Referenced from: ../.theano/compiledir_Darwin-13.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.8-64/tmpTqQ0iS/b6135ddd19d268ad3182850548638ec3.so\n  Reason: image not found', '[Dot22(x, w)]')
```

What is going wrong on my side?

Answer (score 3):

From the error message you get it seems like theano cannot find the mkl library file libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib.

How do you configure your theano? especially, the [blas library](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#config.config.blas.ldflags)?

Please check [this section](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#troubleshooting-make-sure-you-have-a-blas-library) of theano installation manual.

Comment: Thanks!! How do I check if Blas is configured properly?

Comment: @Lanc read the installation manual I linked to. it's all there.